# Reading zero-values in MatLab during loop

Tags: matlab, loops, zero

I have encountered a problem in MatLab as I attempt to run a loop.  For each iteration in the loop eigenvalues and eigenvectors for a 3x3 matrix are calculated (the matrix differs with each iteration).  Further, each iteration should always yield one eigenvector of the form [0 a 0], where only the middle-value, a, is non-zero.

I need to obtain the index of the column of the eigenvector-matrix where this occurs.  To do this I set up the following loop within my main-loop (where the matrix is generated):

```
for i = 1:3
    if (eigenvectors(1,i)==0) && (eigenvectors(3,i)==0)
        index_sh = i
    end
end
```

The problem is that the eigenvector matrix in question will sometimes have an output of the form:

```
eigenvectors =

   -0.7310   -0.6824         0
         0         0    1.0000
    0.6824   -0.7310         0
```

and in this case my code works well, and I get `index_sh = 3.`  However, sometimes the matrix is of the form:

```
eigenvectors =

    0.0000    0.6663    0.7457
   -1.0000    0.0000    0.0000
   -0.0000   -0.7457    0.6663
```

And in this case, MatLab does not assign any value to `index_sh` even though I want `index_sh` to be equal to 1 in this case.

If anyone knows how I can tackle this problem, so that MatLab assigns a value also when the zeros are written as `0.0000` I would be very grateful!

Comment: Looks like the usual float precision issue. Use a tolerance. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686439/why-is-24-0000-not-equal-to-24-0000-in-matlab

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how I can get around this somehow?

Comment: Try to use eigenvectors(1,i)==0.0. Tell me if it works. Another option is using any(eigenvectors(1,i)) as a condition. I also suspect that elements are nonzero in your case, so I would better use the condition like abs(eigenvectors(1,i))<0.0000001 (a very small number)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, very likely, that those "`0.0000`" are not exactly `0`. To solve that, choose a tolerance and use it when comparing with 0:

```
tol = 1e-6;
index_sh = find(abs(eigenvectors(1,:))<tol & abs(eigenvectors(3,:))<tol);
```

In your code:

```
for ii = 1:3
    if abs(eigenvectors(1,ii))<tol && abs(eigenvectors(3,ii))<tol
        index_sh = i
    end
end
```

---

Or, instead of a tolerance, you could choose the column whose first- and third-row entries are closer to 0:

```
[~, index_sh] = min(abs(eigenvectors(1,:)) + abs(eigenvectors(3,:)));
```

Comment: @Kristian Welcome :-) See edit, which avoids the use of a tolerance

Comment: Yes, I noticed it :).  Thanks again!